# Invalid argument supplied for foreach with code

Tags: php

the code below gives me an Invalid argument supplied for foreach. please help

```
if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {  
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($_SESSION["qty"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['qty'];

        $update_qty = mysqli_query("update cart set qty='$qty' LIMIT 1");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($update_qty)) {
            $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;
        }
        $total = $total * $each_item['qty'];
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Session started ? 2. What is the output of: `var_dump($_SESSION["qty"]);` ?

Comment: There will be nothing to fetch on an update... You also are mixing drivers... `mysql_fetch_array` and `mysqli_query`.

Comment: you are not supposed to do ** while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($update_qty)) {
            $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;
        } ** for an update query ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of questions regarding this sort of error. First its a warning not an error so your code will continue to work just fine. You can suppress by using `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` which will only show errors that are fatal. Otherwise in your code if you dont want to see this error you need to do something like..

```
//only try loop if there is an array
if(is_array($_SESSION["qty"])){ 
  foreach ($_SESSION["qty"] as $each_item) { 
    $item_id = $each_item['qty'];

    $update_qty = mysqli_query("update cart set qty='$qty' LIMIT 1");
    //change to mysqli_fetch_array!!
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($update_qty)) {
        //you will only get one row in here like this
        $_SESSION['qty']=$qty; //maybe do $_SESSION['qty'][]=$qty;
    }
    $total = $total * $each_item['qty'];
  }
}else{
   echo 'No array to be found here';
}
```

Comment: No probs. I would worry about this line `$_SESSION['qty']=$qty` it doesnt make obvious sense. I think you want to create an array of the values in `$qty` if so see my comment. I also cant see where `$qty` is initialised so this maybe why you expect an array but you are not seeing one